# Which Cross platform Mobile Development is best for HTML5 to Android,Iphone,Windows

Tags: mobile, cross-platform

I want to develop cross platform mobile app. I have seen frameworks listed below but It will take so much time to test each and every framework, so I am looking here for some advise.

Please guide me which framework is the best and most mature.

I want to do ...

```
HTML5 -> Android, Windows Mobile, Iphone/Ipad


Rhodes and RhoSync
PhoneGAP
Titanium Mobile
QuickConnectFamily
BedRock
Corona
MoSync SDK
Sancha Touch
JQ Touch
iWebKit
iUI
xUI
Magic Framework
Dashcode
CiUI
Safire
iPhone-universal
WebApp.net
The Dojo ToolKit
Jo
```

It should also support a good debuggin support, debugging like in java line by line debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally depends on where you stand in which platform.

Let's say you have strong JavaScript and Jquery knowledge then you can move on with Jquery Mobile and HTML5 to develop any cross platform application.

You can always study pross and cons of above listed stuff but this is quiet subjective stuff.

I will go with following.

1. Sancha Touch
2. PhoneGAP
3. Titanium Mobile
4. Jquery Mobile (Best for Browser Based mobile apps)

Any other you pick below this is fine.

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: Does Titanium Mobile provides HTML5 to windows Mobile app conversion?

Answer (score 1):

If it is Windows Phone(I assume since windows mobile is quite old) you are looking for it is a bit tricky because most of the frameworks do not support it properly yet ([see](http://www.codefessions.com/2012/04/which-mobile-javascript-framework-is.html)) but for Android and iOS you could any HTML5 UI framework and one of the packaging tools such as PhoneGap, MoSync, Sencha or ...

I think Jigar has point and it is subjective, but personally I think titanium mobile is not quite HTML5 although it provides native user interface from JavaScript (which you also get from  MoSync with more HTML5ish code).

Another point is that things like JavaScript frameworks and packagers complement each other for example jQuery Mobile can be used together with PhoneGap or MoSync.

From user experience point of view I prefer the following frameworks:

1. Native
2. Kendo UI
3. jQuery Mobile
4. Sencha